# i'm trying to build a regex which includes 1 character and a number.But couldn't made the regex

Tags: regex

the regex i have tried: `^(?=.*[A-Za-z\@$!%*#?&])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{6,}$` but it doesn't include all special character as character.

What is the shortest way to write the regex which will include all special character.

My regex strategy is:

1. Must contain a character(can be a special character but not number).
2. Must contain a number.
3. Atleast 6 in length

Comment: Probably search before asking. We have what must be a cubic parsec of these password validation regex questions, all different in some minute detail but quite similar in structure. Also, without knowledge of which regex engine or tool you are using, you are making it harder to answer; please review the [`regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
^(?=.*[.\D])(?=.*\d)[\D\d\S]{6,}$
```

or

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\_\=\+\{\[\}\]\|\\\;\:\"\'\,\.\<\>\/\?\~\`])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\_\=\+\{\[\}\]\|\\\;\:\"\'\,\.\<\>\/\?\~\`]{6,}$
```